# file_input is not refilled on changeset error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a form defined like this:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, image_path(@conn, :create), 
             [multipart: true], fn f -> %>
```

And with a text_input for example:

```
= text_input f, :something
```

if my changeset doesnt validate it, i.e., is required, the changeset error callback will take care of refill the text input again, the data is stored in changeset.changes.something

But however, thats not working when uploading a file through Arc module
https://github.com/stavro/arc

```
# web/templates/image/new.html.eex
<h2>Upload a new image</h2>
<%= form_for @changeset, image_path(@conn, :create), 
             [multipart: true], fn f -> %>
  <div class=”form-group”>
    <label>Image</label>
    <%= file_input f, :image %>
    <%= error_tag f, :image %>
  </div>
  <div class=”form-group”>
    <%= submit “Submit”, class: “btn btn-default” %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

On upload the object looks like this:

```
Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/jpeg",
   filename: "IMG.JPG",
   path: "/tmp/plug-1527/multipart-1527258635-945001603407138-1"},
```

and on changeset error, it looks like this inside the changeset:

```
   %{image: %{file_name: "IMG.JPG",
     updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2018-05-25 14:17:49>},
```

But the file input, `<%= file_input f, :image %>` is not refilled, and if the user uploaded an image and forgot to write the required fields he have to upload the image again, is it possible on the changeset callback refill the file input?

Comment: AFAIR, `file_input`s are not refilled by default because this field is to contain _a user local path_, which is not known by the server. Putting just `"IMG.JPG"` there makes not much sense since this field requires a full path to the file _on user’s machine_.

Comment: mm I tried also to update the changeset with the full path through put_change(changeset, :image, "full path") but it didnt work somehow

Comment: You don’t have an access to the full path. Yours makes a little sense, it’s to be, as I said, **the full path on the user’s computer**. Since you don’t have an access to it, you are prevented from filling this field with a garbage data. The only way to overcome this would be to store the entered path in user’s cookie/localstore and restore it on page reload with javascript.